# Adding new subscriber to MailChimp returns Bad Request

Tags: c#, restsharp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

In order to add a subscriber to MailChimp list using API 3.0 the parameters e-mailadress and status are required. If the request succeeds the response will contain the id in json-format.

My problem is that when I use my Member Class to add a subscriber the request sends the id, which is null, and therefore I get the error Bad Request. How can I change my Member class to only read the id from the response and not add it in the request? I'm using RestSharp, Visual Studio 2013, .Net 4.0,

My member class looks like this

```
public class Member
{            
    public Member(){}
    public Member(string status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Member(string email_address, string status)
    {
        this.status = status;
        this.email_address = email_address;
    }
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

And my createMember function looks like this:

```
static void createMember()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://" + dc + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0");

    //HTML Basic Authentification
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(usernsme, apiKey);

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.Resource = "lists/{list_id}/members";

    request.AddUrlSegment("list_id", listId);

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    request.AddBody(new Member(memberEmail, "subscribed"));

    RestClient.AddHandler();
    IRestResponse<Member> response2 = client.Execute<Member>(request);
    string _id = response2.Data.id;

    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(_id);
}
```

I can add a subscriber to a list if I remove the id from the Member Class but how can then get the Id from the response and work with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [their reference](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/), the API method you're calling has different the request body parameters and response body parameters, so I'd suggest using two different classes. The first one would be `MemberRequest`, which is for the request and doesn't have the `id` field

```
public class MemberRequest
{
    public MemberRequest(){}

    public MemberRequest(string status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public MemberRequest(string email_address, string status)
    {
        this.status = status;
        this.email_address = email_address;
    }

    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

and the second one would be `MemberResponse`, which is for the response and has the `id` field

```
public class MemberResponse
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how your `createMember` method would look like

```
static void createMember()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://" + dc + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0");

    //HTML Basic Authentification
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(usernsme, apiKey);

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.Resource = "lists/{list_id}/members";

    request.AddUrlSegment("list_id", listId);

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    request.AddBody(new MemberRequest(memberEmail, "subscribed"));

    IRestResponse<MemberResponse> response = client.Execute<MemberResponse>(request);
    string _id = response.Data.id;

    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(_id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for.